# ASP.Net FileNotFoundException on server but not in VS

Tags: asp.net, filenotfoundexception

I added a reference to a DLL in my ASP.Net app. That started causing a BadFileFormatException, so I switched my app to target x86. I'm now getting this error:

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TheDLLThatIReferenced.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.*

The DLL in question is present in both the bin directory, and in bin\x86\Debug in my app's directory on the server. When I try to run my app out of Visual Studio, it runs just fine, but if I try to hit it via the internet, I get that error.

What might be causing this error, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Permission issues? Does the ASP.NET process have access to where this asssembly lives (a long shot perhaps.). Although it should be copied into the bin folder...ummm

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've seen this it has boiled down to the assembly not being where it ought to on the server.

Have you confirmed that the web site you are hitting on the server is actually pointed at the directory you are looking at?

Comment: I think so. If I hit "explore" in IIS, it points to my project's directory. I can see the bin directory there. Is there more that I can/need to check?

Answer (score 0):

put **validateRequest=false** on asp.net page that is throwing Java.io.FileNotFoundException.